# Listview index changed show item

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display the current selected item in the first column of a listview row. The problem is, since this is in the listviewindexchanged event, that let's say the selected item is Michael. When I choose Bob, I get a messagebox for Michael, and for Bob, when really it should just be for Bob. How can I fix this?

```
Sub ListView1SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox(listView1.Items(listView1.FocusedItem.Index).Text)       
    End Sub
```

Comment: The event is triggered twice, once for the unselected item and once for the selected item. You only want to handle the second case.

Comment: ...also the FocusedItem is not the same as the SelectedItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try displaying your message on a different event, say the mouse click event.